# Anyone knows PrimeNG DataTable LazyLoading in Angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I want to implement PrimeNG DataTable LazyLoading in Angular 2 but there is no realtime example i found on internet.

I have already referred below PrimeNG site which shows lazy loading with dummy data:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/lazy

Has anyone implemented by calling BE service? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a service for this if you use angular cli you can add with

```
ng generate service services/CarService
```

after that you need to call service (maybe web api) then you need to inject your service to you lazy load component

```
constructor(private carService: CarService) { }
```

then you can use your lazyload datatable. In this example your web api need to return data cars and totalcars(for pagination)

```
this.carService.getCarsLarge().then(cars => {
            this.datasource = cars; 
            this.totalRecords = this.datasource.length;
            this.cars = this.datasource.slice(0, 10);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @Snr for your reply. I was expecting a realtime example which is not mentioned in PrimeNG DataTable documentation. Do you know any such example? That would be really helpful.